Batch Job (Fargate task) cannot pull image from ECR
I'm struggling to understand what VPC configurations are necessary to enable AWS Batch Jobs, running in a Fargate compute environment, to retrieve images from ECR.
vpc.ts
    // Create VPC
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `VPC-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`, {
      maxAzs: 3, // Maximum number of Availability Zones to use
      natGateways: 1, // Number of NAT Gateways to use
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          name: `PublicSubnet-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
        },
        {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
          name: `PrivateSubnet-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
        },
      ],
    });

    // Add VPC endpoint for ECR API
    this.ecrApiEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `EcrApiEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR,
      },
    );
    // Add VPC endpoint for ECR Docker
    this.ecrDkrEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `EcrDkrEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR_DOCKER,
      },
    );
    // Optionally, you can add VPC endpoint for CloudWatch Logs if you're logging in a private subnet
    this.cloudwatchLogsEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `CloudwatchLogsEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.CLOUDWATCH_LOGS,
      },
    );

    this.securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `SecurityGroup-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`, {
      vpc: this.vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });
  }
}

However, the error that I get is
CannotPullContainerError: The task cannot pull <image>. There is a connection issue between the task and the registry. Check your task network configuration. : failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get <image>: i/o timeout

So I'm really curious, what more could be needed to enable Tasks to pull images from ECR?

We have a Java example for this that works. That is, the Java API examples will show you how to enable AWS Batch Jobs, running in a Fargate compute environment, to retrieve images from ECR.
To get a docker image on ECR - follow this example:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/ecr/src/main/java/com/example/ecr/scenario/ECRScenario.java
To get the image from ECR to Fargate - see this example:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/batch/src/main/java/com/example/batch/scenario

Make sure the task execution role (not the job role) has permissions to pull from ECR.
